# MVC4 validation summary not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Have created a model and with required fields and used to create a form like so:

Model:

```
public class formModel {
    [Required]
    public string name {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string Add1 {get;set;}
    etc....
}
```

View:

```
@model myProj.Models.formModel

@using (BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(f => f.Add1)
    etc...

    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(formModel f)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do Stuff here
        return RedirectToAction("Result");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Form", new { id = "showForm" });
 }
```

Problem is the validation summary is being displayed if the model is in valid. Have used same approach on lots of other forms and has been fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the model is invalid, do not use

```
return RedirectToAction("Form");
```

But

```
return View(f); // or return View("ViewName", f);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the form is in a partial view and the name of the action doesn't relate directly the name of the views. The form only gets shown when the correct ID is added onto the end of the Action in the url. Have edited original code.

Comment: Remember that the modelstate is not stored in the `TempData` or something, so after a redirect it is gone and so are the validation messages. When you use forms in a partial that are shown on certain conditions, or multiple forms on a page, consider using an AJAX approach.